# Can delayed choice experiment be observed live?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, experimental-physics, electrons, double-slit-experiment

In delayed choice experiment an observer is added to observe the path of electron which results in interference pattern changing to clump pattern.

So if the experiment is conducted live and if watching the final screen it will show interference pattern and now suddenly you add the observer and it changes to clump pattern and I will be able to watch that live?

Comment: Have you read any practical descriptions of the delayed-choice experiments? Many popularizations are not very good.

Comment: No I haven't but I will. I'm not a physicist, im a regular person asking because I found it interesting. If you have done the practical then please tell if you can see such a live change. I have seen normal double slit experiment with photons so I understand a bit and I'll understand if u explain.